# Access logs from docker container

Tags: python, docker, logging, dockerfile

I have a python server that I run in a docker container. I log my messages with logging from python and I don't know how to find/view my log file from the container.

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3

# Copy code to the container
ADD src /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

# run configuration
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Start script
CMD [ "python", "./main.py"]
```

I start the server like this:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 5000:5000 --rm my_app
```

How can I access server logs?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use -v parameter in your "docker run" to mount your host folder to a folder in container.

```
    sudo docker run -it -p 5000:5000 -v hostPath:containerPathContainingLogs --rm my_app
```

Then you will view your log in hostPath(It is mapped into containerPathContainingLogs in your container).

Or in another way, if your docker image contains bash, you can use docker ps -a, to find the container id you run, and "docker exec -it your-container-id bash" to login your container, cd to your log path and view your log.

Or you can try docker logs your-container-id.

Answer (score 5):

You can always check direct docker output of your service with:

```
docker logs my-container-instance
```

To check the log path file you can use:

```
docker inspect my-cintainer-instance
```

and find for the `LogPath` key on the json output.

Answer (score 4):

docker logs --tail 200 -f docker-container-id

Answer (score 2):

Just use this command :

```
docker logs CONTAINER ID
```

( Ex :  docker logs c587105f2a4f )

To get the running containers, and container id use the command :

```
docker ps
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answers given if you want to redirect your logs to the file use this

docker logs containername >& logfile